# phonegap filewriter append issue

Tags: android, cordova

Trying to use phonegap 0.9.6 file storage. The code works fine while I am writing a file but does not work when I try to append to the file (using seek, truncate etc.).

There was a bug in version 0.9.5 that seems to be fixed.

The code just terminates when I call writer.seek. The alert after truncate (or if I delete the truncate the seek) is not being called at all.

Should I set an append flag somewhere? The doc says that but does not give an example as to where I should be setting the append flag.  The code is as follows

```
function gotFS(fileSystem) {
        fileSystem.root.getFile( "test.txt", {"create":true,
            "exclusive":false}, gotFileEntry, fail);
    }

    function gotFileEntry(fileEntry) {
        fileEntry.createWriter(gotFileWriter, fail);
    }

    function gotFileWriter(writer) {
        writer.onwrite = function(evt) {
            console.log("write success");
        };

        writer.write("some sample text");
        // contents of file now 'some sample text'
        writer.truncate(11);
        alert('truncated');
        // contents of file now 'some sample'
        writer.seek(writer.length); //writer.seek(4) does not work either

        // contents of file still 'some sample' but file pointer is after the 'e' in 'some'
        writer.write(" different text");
        // contents of file now 'some different text'
        alert('success with diff text');
    }
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a workaround to that :

```
        function gotFileWriter(writer) {
            writer.onwrite = function(evt) {
                console.log("write success");
            };

            writer.write("some sample text");
            // contents of file now 'some sample text'
            writer.abort();
            writer.truncate(11);
            // contents of file now 'some sample'
            writer.abort();
            writer.seek(writer.length); //writer.seek(4) does not work either

            // contents of file still 'some sample' but file pointer is after the 'e' in 'some'
            writer.write(" different text");
        }
```

Comment: If I am trying to run it in a loop so it is only printing me first line and on every App relaunch, it appends one line to it.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16192825/failed-to-write-10-lines-to-a-file-using-loop-in-javascript-phonegap

Comment: I would recommend the following approach (making use of the eventhandlers): http://stackoverflow.com/a/23836103/925861

Answer (score 1):

The file handling is asynchron. You can't simply do the file operations step by step. You have to wait for the onwrite events, before making the next step. 
writer.abort() may fix the error. But you can't be sure what is stored.

Comment: Thanks for this comment. I ended up queueing writes, and waiting for FileWriter `onwriteend` before performing next write. Performing multiple simultaneous writes results in code 7, INVALID_STATE.