# Failed to write 10 lines to a file using loop in Javascript (PhoneGap)

Tags: java, javascript, android, cordova, for-loop

I am trying to write atleast 10 lines to a file using loops to append multiple lines in a file using PhoneGap, but everytime I run this code below, only able to add 1 line to a file as a newline. But 10 lines are not being printed in 10 iteration. Please suggest me how to rectify my problem using phoneGap javascript.

```
function gotFileWriter(writer) {

                    for (var z = 0; z<= 10; z++) {

                        console.log("normal write success");

                        writer.onwrite = function(evt) {

                            console.log("write success");
                        };


                        writer.onwriteend = function(evt) {

                            console.log("write end");
                        }

                        writer.seek(writer.length);
                        writer.write("id,updated,created,fname,lname,company,tags,type,label,value,source,sourceid\r\n");
                        writer.abort();    // I tried even commenting
                    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This did the trick for me

Build one big string:

```
function gotFileWriter(writer)
{
  var bigString = '';
  for (var i=0; i<numberOfLines; i++)
  {
    bigString += line[i];
    bigString += '\r\n';
  }
...
```

Then do a massive write to the file:

```
...
  writer.onwrite = function (evt) { ... };
  writer.onwriteend = function (evt) { ... };
  writer.seek(writer.length);
  writer.write (bigString);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you try this ?

```
function gotFileWriter(writer) {

    console.log("normal write success");

    writer.onwrite = function(evt) {
        console.log("write success");
    };


    writer.onwriteend = function(evt) {
        console.log("write end");
    }


    for (var z = 0; z< 10; z++) {

        writer.seek(writer.length);
        writer.write("id,updated,created,fname,lname,company,tags,type,label,value,source,sourceid\r\n");
        writer.abort();    // I tried even commenting
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this for appending the text to file instead of looping

```
function gotFileWriter(writer) {
    writer.seek(writer.length);
    writer.write(" - append- \n");
}
```