# How to delete contents of text file in phonegap?

Tags: cordova

Can you please tell me how to delete the contend of text file in phonegap?
I have text file having some text on it .I want to remove that text before inserting the new text .Is this possible in phonegap? 
I am able to read , write , delete file .But how to remove the contends of file?

Answer (score 5):

You can use Truncate.

It is just a little more complicated if you are going to write afterwards.  You can't just

```
writer.truncate(0);
writer.write("Leo was here");
```

If you do that neither seems to work but each one works individually. So to make it work you have to wait until the truncate finishes before doing the write. Add the write in the onwriteend of the truncate. NB It is important to clear or change the onwwriteend otherwise you will get an infinite loop.

So start by getting the filesystem and use the filesystem to get the file entry

```
function clearFile(fileName){
    window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, function(fileSystem){
                         fileSystem.root.getFile(fileName, { create: false }, clearfileExists, fileDoesNotExist);
                         }, getFSFail); 
}
```

assuming you got a file entry (the file exists) then create the filewriter.

```
function clearfileExists(fileEntry){
    console.log("File " + fileEntry.fullPath + " exists!");
    fileEntry.createWriter(truncateFile, fileDoesNotExist);
}
```

Now that you have a file writer. call truncate(0) and in the onwriteend clear the onwrite end and write what you want.

```
function truncateFile(writer){
    console.log("truncate");
    writer.onwriteend= function(evt) {
        LOG("write");
        writer.seek(0);
        writer.onwriteend = function(evt){
            console.log("contents of file now 'Leo was Here'");
        }
        writer.write("Leo was Here");
    }
    writer.truncate(0);
}
```

and for completeness here is the handling of the error cases

```
function fileDoesNotExist(){
    console.log("file does not exist");
}
function getFSFail(evt) {
    console.log(evt.target.error.code);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the truncate method to remove all the contents down to a certain amount or if you were getting rid of everything you could always delete the file and create a new empty version.

```
function win(writer) {
    writer.truncate(0);
};

var fail = function(evt) {
    console.log(error.code);
};

file.createWriter(win, fail);
```

Answer (score 0):

### The `Cordova File Plugin` can get quite `cumbersome`.  In this `GIST`, I've broken down `file operations` into multiple pieces with the help of `Promises` and was able to achieve the following `operations`:

This is what it looks like:

- `get a file` if it already exists.
- `save the fileWriter` in memory
- `read from the file` and store the data in memory
- `remove the file` with the saved (in-memory) fileWriter reference.
- `create a new file` with the same name.
- `update the content` with `saved content` + `new content`
- `write` this content to the `file`

Excerpt from [gist](https://gist.github.com/appsparkler/cc4b5269ab59130446e0aecd33ee5fea):

```
var fileName = 'test-450.json';
var fileData;
var savedFileEntry = {};

promise_getPersistentDirectoryEntry()
  .then(promise_fileEntry.bind(null, fileName, { create:false }))
  .then(save_fileEntry)
  .then(promise_file)
  .then(promise_fileContent)
  .then(save_fileData)
  .then(remove_fileEntry)
  .then(promise_getPersistentDirectoryEntry)
  .then(promise_fileEntry.bind(null, fileName, {create:true}))
  .then(promise_fileWriter)
  .then(edit_content)
  .then(promise_writeContent)
  .then(promise_getPersistentDirectoryEntry)
  .then(promise_fileEntry.bind(null, fileName, {create:false}))
  .then(promise_file)
  .then(promise_fileContent)
  .then(res => {
      logit('JSON.parse(res.target.result)', JSON.parse(res.target.result));
      // logit('savedFileEntry', savedFileEntry);
      logit('fileData', fileData);
    })

  .catch(err => logit('err', err));
```

[This is the Gist](https://gist.github.com/appsparkler/cc4b5269ab59130446e0aecd33ee5fea)

Good Luck...